# Xcode: horizontal constraints are not respected?

Tags: swift, xcode, constraints

The result today is:

[image]

As you can see there is an error with the view which contains both Labels doesn't respect the constraint between icon and its.

Global constraints:

[image]

Did you see some configuration errors guys on constraints?

Comment: Presumably an ambiguity, but no need to guess. Run the app to get the issue, and switch to the View Debugger. Look for exclamation marks. You’ll find the problem instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you getting constraint issue in your "Xib" or "Storyboard" because when I added the same constraints that you have used, I am getting constraint conflict issue.

After correcting it, It is like this now:

[image]

First the `Texts layout.centerX = centreX` is not required if you are adding leading and trailing.

Second `Icon View.leading = leading + 16` if you want the icon view to stick to the left side.